# Why my query kept repeating fields after Left Join in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

i have two table in my database with one-to-many relation that an announcement(annonce) can have multiple or Zero attachments(pdf).
what i want is to get all attachments(pdf) that they have same title(titre in my database) without repeating the title.
here is what i've tried

```
SELECT *
FROM annonce LEFT JOIN
     pdfannonce
     on annonce.id = pdfannonce.annonce_id
 WHERE categorie = "Emplois du temps" AND
       annonce.destination = "1re Année" or annonce.destination = "Tous"
```

and here's what i get:

[image]

titre have multiple pdf but have one titre, destination, categorie

what i want to get is

```
+----+-------+------------------+----------------+-----------------+
| id | titre |       pdf        |  destination   |   catégorie     |
+----+-------+------------------+----------------+-----------------+
|  1 | book  | my_first_pdf     |   1re anne     | Emploi du temps |
|    |       |    my_second_pdf |                |                 |
+----+-------+------------------+----------------+-----------------+
```

Comment: Without sample data and desired results, your question is not clear.

Comment: So what output would you need instead?

Comment: Use `group by` ?

Comment: what i want is to get all pdf that have same destination and same categories without repeating destination and same categories fields

Comment: groupe by isn't working @Georgy

Comment: I'm not sure I understand still... You could possibly `select pdfannonce.*` only, but you'll lose the `annonce` columns. Could you ASCII-art the desired output maybe? See https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/.

Comment: probably because there is a many-to-one relationship (several rows in the left joined table for a single row in the main table)

Comment: edit your question and do not comment such things.  as you can see in the first two rows, they are almost the same but have differne3ces in id and pdf name. if you want only 1 of them to appear group by

Comment: you can see now this is what i want @sp00m

Comment: So in the PDF column, you want a stringified concatenation of all the PDFs if the annonces share the same title?

Comment: yes that's exaclyt what i want @sp00m

Comment: Well, that's feasible I guess, but it will be a pain to parse back to be honest, I'm not sure that's what you need (I'm afraid we're hitting an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)). Maybe you could do two queries, one `select annonce` and one `select pdfannonce`, and do the matching/grouping with the code receiving the data? Or you just allow duplication/overfetching in that query... What would be the separator you'd need if you do want to go down the concatenation route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your result do this

```
SELECT 
a.id,a.titre ,GROUP_CONCAT(p.pdf),a.destination   ,a.catégorie
FROM annonce a LEFT JOIN
     pdfannonce p
     on a.id = p.annonce_id
 WHERE categorie = "Emplois du temps" AND
       (a.destination = "1re Année" or a.destination = "Tous")
GROUP BY a.id,a.titre,a.destination   ,a.catégorie
```

Themain thing you have to remember you need to do parenthesesaround the where clause of parentheses or else teh result is wrong.

Comment: but the only thing i can have access to my first pdf

Comment: Instead of GROUP_CONCAT you can try another aggregation funcntion, you should experiment with it it ´, because i don't think that Left join is the right choice.

Comment: if i don’t do the Left join i won't be able to get my announcement which has zero pdf 
i will get all announcements with pdfs

Comment: i find a solution a just added a seprator GROUP_CONCAT(p.pdf SEPARATOR ';') and now i can get them separately

Comment: GROUP _CONCAT has as DEFAULT  a comma as SEPARATOR, but ok

Comment: Just make sure you don't use a separator that could be found in the file names, you won't be able to split them back otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear, but your query does not look right.  This is a "better" form of the query:

```
SELECT *
FROM annonce a LEFT JOIN
     pdfannonce p
     on a.id = p.annonce_id AND p.categorie = 'Emplois du temps'
 WHERE a.destination in ('1re Année', 'Tous')
```

I am assuming that `categorie` is coming from `pdfannonce`.  The two changes are:

- The "dangling" `OR` is replaced by `IN`, which is presumably the logic you really want.
- The condition on the second table in the `LEFT JOIN` is in the `ON` clause.

Comment: i get the same result, what i want is to get all pdf that have same destination and same categories without repeating destination and same categories fields